# Como seria o modelo de rotas para uma API Rest em operações mais complexas?

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

Pesquisei um pouco sobre o modelo de API REST, mas dentre muitas dúvidas que eu tinha, me restou uma que é essencialmente importante.

O pessoal sempre dava exemplos de modelos de rotas parecidas com isso:

```
https://api.dominio.com.br/account[/{id}]

GET -> obtem o(s) usuário(s)
POST -> insere um novo usuário
PUT -> atualiza o usuário
DELETE -> remove o usuário
```

Até aí funciona muito bem, eu tenho a opção de manusear todos os usuários ou apenas um, mas só através do ID.

1. Se eu quiser selecionar pelo e-mail ou pelo nome de usuário? Como deveria ser feito?
2. Se eu precisar passar parâmetros mais avançados para a consulta, como um WHERE ou um ORDER BY ou até mesmo um LIMIT, como fazer?

@Edit

Se possível, também gostaria de saber o seguinte: em operações um pouco menos abstratas como enviar um e-mail de recuperação de senha, os processos necessários para tal devem ser feitos na aplicação cliente (que teria que fazer várias requisições a API) ou deve-se criar uma rota que quando chamada realize todas as operações necessárias e entregue uma resposta pronta a aplicação cliente?

A operações para enviar um e-mail de recuperação de senha, são mais ou menos no modelo abaixo:

- Verifica se o usuário existe;
- Verifica se o código de recuperação gerado pela aplicação já foi gerado antes para outro usuário, para evitar códigos duplicados;
- Registra o código de recuperação;
- Obtém o modelo de e-mail para recuperações de senha;
- Envia o e-mail.

Comment: Não é porque esta usando REST que você é obrigado a usar somente o PATH, (caminho do endereço), é totalmente aceitável usar querystring `?foo=bar&baz=foobar`, mas é claro que REST é REST, uma chamada REST não vai fazer uma série de coisar diferentes, então muita coisa vc vai poder acertas no proprio PATH. Pra resumir, você quer multiplas ações e essas ações com certeza ficam bem resolvidas se divididas em diferentes URLs (creio que o Slim tenha grupo de rotas, o que deve ajudar a se organizar)

Comment: Sugiro que você veja esses dois sites: - [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/)
- [REST API tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) Com uma leitura rápida você terá um bom entendimento.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Um pouco de padrões REST(nenhum obrigatório):

**1 - Uso de substantivos ao invés de verbos:**

```
/users - OK
/cars  - OK

/getAllUsers   - NOK
/createNewUser - NOK
/getAllCars    - NOK
```

**2 - GET request não altera o estado do recurso:**

```
GET /users?activate=true - NOK
```

**3 - Paths no plural:**

```
/users - OK
/user  - NOK
```

**4 - Utilização de Sub-Recursos para Identificação de Relacionamento:**

```
GET /users/1234/addresses - Retorna a lista de endereços que o usuário id=1234 possui.
```

**5 - Content-Type e Accept para a definição de Serialização/Deserialização :**

```
curl -XPOST https://api.service.com/v1/users -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:text/xml" -d '{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}'

Resultado:
<root>
    <message>Usuario cadastrado com sucesso</message>
    <entity>
         <id>1234</id>
         <firstName>John</firstName>
         <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    </entity>
</root>
```

**6 - Filtros, Paginação e Ordenação:**

```
GET /users?lastName=Doe&age=18
GET /users?sort=-createdAt,+updatedAt
GET /users?fields=id,firstName,lastName
GET /users?offset=1&limit=10
```

**7 - Versionamento da API**

```
/v1/users
```

**8 - Tratamentos de erros informados com um [HTTP Status](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) e um payload**

```
curl -XPOST https://api.server.com/v1/users -d '{"firstName":'

resposta:
HttpStatus 400 (Bad Request)
{
  "message": "Invalid request body"
}

curl -XPOST https://api.server.com/v1/users -d '{"firstName": null }'

resposta:
HttpStatus 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
{
  "message": "Unable to create the account"
  "errors": [
    {
       "attribute": "firstName",
       "message": "firstName cannot be null"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sobre a questão de recuperação de senha é mais ou menos o que você descreveu. Você pode ter um endpoint que receba o email do usuário e acione outros serviços, ex:

```
POST /passwords {"email": "jondoe@gmail.com"}

1 - API: Valida o cadastro e dispara um evento de recuperação de senha 
2 - Listener do Evento: Registra uma solicitação na base, dispara um email e um SMS (two factor)
```

O fluxo varia de acordo com a necessidade de cada aplicação.

Comment: Colocou uma resposta enorme e não respondeu de forma direta e clara o que foi perguntado.

Comment: +1 pelo "cheat sheet" de API REST. Sobre o comentário acima, a primeira pergunta está respondida no item 6,  e a do "@edit" está no final...

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo utilizando seu exemplo (recuperação de senha via email), podemos olhar [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310442/how-to-design-rest-api-for-email-sending-service), onde é dito:

[Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548696/tadeck) (2012) - Você pode usar Controllers como alternativas para executar ações mais complexas. No seu caso, elas podem ficar assim:

```
(action)           (verb)   (URI)                          (type)
create:            POST   - /emails                         - collection
retrieve:          GET    - /email/{id}                     - resource
update:            PUT    - /email/{id}                     - resource
delete:            DELETE - /email/{id}                     - resource
send immediately:  POST   - /email/{id}/sendImmediately     - controller
just send:         POST   - /email/{id}/send                - controller
do something else: POST   - /email/{id}/someOtherActionType - controller
```

Se você souber inglês, recomendo a leitura do "[Livro de Receitas REST](http://restcookbook.com/)"